# Can I use a 400W graphics card with a 450W PSU?

Tags: graphics-card, power-supply

This is the first time I'll be trying any graphics card. My primary concern is not to play games but running video and image editing software smoothly.

I found some good low range card (e.g. AMD/ATI RADEON HD 6570 1 GB DDR3, AMD/ATI RADEON HD 6450 2 GB DDR3 etc.). But they demand a 400W power supply.

I have a 450W SMPS having following tag on it:

[image]

This is already taking the load of supplying power to 2 RAMs, 1 CPU, 3 HDD, and 1 DVD drive.

Can I give a load of such graphics card on it? Am I measuring it correctly? Or I need to look for some alternate card which may run on low power supply?

Comment: It's unclear:  Do you mean that the specs for the card say you must have a 400W power supply?  If so then a 450W unit should be quite fine, so long as there are no other unusual loads in the box.  If you mean that the card says it uses 400W by itself (which would be an awful lot) then a 450W power supply would be marginal at best.

Comment: Yes, the specs for the card says for 400W power supply.

Comment: Since 450W is > 400W you're in great shape.

Comment: As per [this](http://in.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20130607101241AARG62m) answer, a 400W graphic card may not properly run on your PSU. Because power supply 18A on the +12V rail provides maximum 216 watts.

Comment: Oh ! I am again confused now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AMD 6570X series are mid range card with typical power draw of ~ 75 watt (Graphics card only)

The system power consumption (typical) with a I7 920 with maximum load is around 250 watt

So 400 watt is more than enough that series

[image: Total system power consumption running MSI Kombuster benchmark]

Image credit [AMD 6570 HD review Neoseeker.com](http://www.neoseeker.com/Articles/Hardware/Reviews/amd_hd_6670_6570/13.html)

Comment: Finally purchased Graphics card and it is working fine.